# What happens if you fail the review audit several times in a row?

Tags: discussion, review-audit

What happens if you fail the review audit several times in a row? Do you get suspended from reviewing? I have failed 4 review audits in the close vote category in the last few days and since today I cannot find any close vote questions in the queue. Am I suspended?

Comment: No. There are no review related suspensions (I guess an extremely disruptive reviewer might earn one eventually, but we don't have those). You may get banned from reviewing for a brief period, and IIRC a matching message should then pop up, when you attempt to review. The few review bans I have given were consequences of several problems visible in the review stats of the user. Audit failures should be primarily seen as the system telling you to slow down. So failing audits **alone** is not a problem.

Comment: (cont'd) But if it looks like audit failures might be a consequence of spending something like 6 seconds per review task (often accompanied by heavily skewed decision stats - one way or the other), then it looks bad. Anyway you should get a friendly reminder/warning before a ban.

Comment: A "friendly" reminder, eh?  Like this: "Congratulations!  If you continue auditing as you have, you will be rewarded with an audit ban!"

Comment: @GEdgar: I like to think that the warning would be more detailed :-). Like telling exactly what kind of problems have been observed. Preferrably with links to occasions, where the view taken by this reviewer went against the community consensus. Or just expressing a concern about specific aspects of review stats of the user in question.

Comment: Mind you, I hope to learn from the discussion (if any) in this thread. My views of when to use review bans have not converged. IMHO robo-reviewing is the one practice I really would like to weed out. It's immaterial whether it is motivated by badge-hunting or a pro/anti-closure campaign.

Comment: Not that I have been the most active reviewer, but I have never failed an audit. If the close vote seems much pettier than what you normally see, it's probably a fake question.

Answer (score 14):

> What happens if you fail the review audit several times in a row? Do you get suspended from reviewing?

When one fails enough review audits, the system issues an automatic review ban (of length between two and thirty days). I don't know what number or proportion "enough" is, but it's not the crucial point whether these failures are in consecutive audits or there are passed audits in between, just the number or proportion of (recently) failed audits matters.

Independent from the review audits, moderators can issue manual (timed) review bans when they become aware of serious reviewing issues. In particular egregious cases, reviewing misbehaviour can even lead to a suspension of the account.

> I have failed 4 review audits in the close vote category in the last few days

I count five failed audits (of fourteen) in the close vote review queue in the last thirty days. That's not alarming, but it's still relatively high. However, with an average duration of 48.4 seconds per review, it doesn't look like you're robo-reviewing, rather that your criteria for whether to vote to close or leave open a question are particularly strict. Looking at these failed audits, I see two questions where I can see possible reasons to vote to close, and three where I don't see any.

> and since today I cannot find any close vote questions in the queue. Am I suspended?

No,

[image]

you have reached the daily limit of twenty reviews per queue, and so you can't review any close votes until tomorrow.

Review bans are not per-queue, they are global. If you were review-banned, you could not make *any* reviews while the ban is in place.

Comment: Also, in case of ban there would be an explanatory message on the review page: either with the standard "you've made too many incorrect reviews", or with some [moderator-entered text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311385).